# How do I get rid of polarity signs of source?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

My code

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0)
    to[sV, v<=$V$] ++(0,2.5)
    to[R, l=$R$,i=$i$,-o] ++(3.5,0)
    to[open, v^=$~~U$] ++(0,-2.5)
    to[short,-o] ++(0,0)
    --(0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Gives me

[image]

I want

[image]

How do I remove polarity signs from the voltage source?

Comment: If I add the necessary pieces to turn your code fragment into a compilable document, I don't get the + and - sign. Make a [mre] that will allow people to reproduce your problem

Comment: I have added minimum code that still displays the issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[
american,
]{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
\draw
(0,0)
    to[sV, voltage/american plus/.initial={}, voltage/american minus/.initial={}, v<=$V$] ++(0,2.5)
    to[R, l=$R$,i=$i$,-o] ++(3.5,0)
    to[open, v^=$~~U$] ++(0,-2.5)
    to[short,-o] ++(0,0)
    --(0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked for V but it also removed the signs for U. How can I add the polarity signs over U?

Comment: @asasasasas If you want the changes to only apply to the V, you can make them locally